# Extract a substring using regex in Spring expression language

Tags: java, regex, regular-language, spring-el

I have a String like

String 1 : `abcdefgh{EID##00000000001234567890##EID}khkgfhjjh`

String 2 : `qwertyuiop{EID##00000000001234567890##EID}asdaff`

and I want the output 1234567890 , if `EID##...##EID` is present in String1 , if not present it will search in string 2. If not present in both result will be 00000000

*But I can use ONLY Spring Expression language.*

I tried something like :

```
${String1}.indexOf('EID##') != -1 AND ${String1}.indexOf('##EID') != -1 AND (${String1}.indexOf('##EID') - ${String1}.indexOf('EID##'))> 5
? 
(${String1}.substring(${String1}.indexOf('EID##')+5,${String1}.indexOf('##EID'))).replaceAll("^0+", "") 
: 
(${String2}.indexOf('EID##') != -1 AND ${String2}.indexOf('##EID') != -1 AND (${String2}.indexOf('##EID') - ${String2}.indexOf('EID##'))> 5  
? 
(${String2}.substring(${String2}.indexOf('EID##')+5,${String2}.indexOf('##EID'))).replaceAll("^0+", "")
: 
'0000000000')
```

But the problem is I have a characters limit of 350.(This is 523 characters)
Is there a simpler way to this?

Comment: Two questions: why can you only use Spring Expression language? Why is the character limit 350?

Comment: PS: Removing unnecessary spaces, newlines, changing `!= -1` to `<0` and stuff like that already lowers the character-count a bit, although 470 characters is still too long. ;) Changing the `String1` and `String2` to something smaller like `a` and `b` would lower it to 386 characters. Creating a variable for `'EID##'` would make it somewhat equal to 350. Unfortunately I don't know the Spring Expression language at all..

Comment: In Java 10+ I could do this [in 125 characters](https://tio.run/##tZBNb8IwDIbv/Ioo3aHtaATsm66dJm2TdtiJ47SD2yZtSmhL4zAh1N9ewoCdkMZlvtiW31f24xJWEJTZvE8VaE0@QFabASEaAWVKSjtlBqViwlQpyrpib4ficYatrPLhWZp9jmMiSNQnQQxBvFlBSzCizH99f3Gcke@yS89xbMN8GrYcTVsRYHxpQGkXImAtbxSk/FkpF4f0Ykw97yk5CjBKTgro6BB0ilMIuz4cWLzGJMriHShXtczIwpK7@zs/vwh4uy8QMltr5AtWG2SNHaGqXMGgadTapctv3uLayLrZ7BF@Yzy5ur65vbt/GP0AdaAzEIJ6RyckacZFXvzlmxfzXBRlWViS8B/vQa5xfNaOnXJy2tgNun4L). I'm pretty active on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. ;)

Comment: I am using a tool(it's for official use) which allows only Spring Expression lang, and internally it stores this expression in a non-customizable table in database whose column size is 350

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, its working.

(${String1} matches '.*EID##.*##EID.*') ? (${String1}.substring(${String1}.indexOf('EID##')+5,${String1}.indexOf('##EID'))).replaceAll("^0+", "") : 
((${String2} matches '.*EID##.*##EID.*') ? (${String2}.substring(${String2}.indexOf('EID##')+5,${String2}.indexOf('##EID'))).replaceAll("^0+", "") : '000000000')